# Cordova FileTransfer download. Error code 1 with IOS only: "Could not create target file"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I'm using FileTransfer and FileOpener to download then view a file within an Ionic application, using the native file opener to view the file.

With IOS, when I attempt to download specific files (in this case PDF), I get the error:

{"code": 1, 
...
"Could not create target file"}

This works with some documents (all the same size) and with others it works fine.

```
  viewFile() {
this.analytics.trackEvent('document', 'view/download', this.document.originalFileName);
let fileName = this.document.originalFileName;
let filePath = `${this.file.dataDirectory}downloads/${fileName}`;
this.fileTransfer.download(this.document.fileUrl, filePath)
  .then(file => {
    this.openFile(filePath, fileName);
    this.analytics.trackEvent('document', 'view/download', this.insightId);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
  });
  this.close();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had with this was it wasn't accepting whitespaces.

I had to URI encode and decode the fileName (if it had a whitespace in it).

The following now works:

```
viewFile() {
    this.analytics.trackEvent('document', 'view/download', this.document.originalFileName);
    let fileName = encodeURI(this.document.originalFileName);
    let filePath = "${this.file.dataDirectory}downloads/${fileName}";
    this.fileTransfer.download(this.document.fileUrl, filePath)
      .then(file => {
        this.openFile(filePath, fileName);
        this.analytics.trackEvent('document', 'view/download', this.insightId);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}");
      });
      this.close();
  }

  openFile(filePath, fileName) {
    let mimeType = mime.lookup(fileName);
    this.fileOpener.open(decodeURI(filePath), mimeType)
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.status === 9) {
          this.messageService.sendMessage(new ErrorMessage("No viewer found for this file type"));
        }
        console.log("error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}");
      });
  }
```